# Surface has already been released: when drawing with Canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

My program draws an oval when we click on the screen and + changes the coordinates of the oval depending on the coordinates of the held finger. When we release the finger, the oval should disappear.

Now when I click on the screen I get my oval and + when I move my finger the oval is always next to it, but when I release my finger I get an error:

> E/Surface: freeAllBuffers: 1 buffers were freed while being dequeued!
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
> Process: com.example.lab10, PID: 24198
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Surface has already been released.
> at android.view.Surface.checkNotReleasedLocked(Surface.java:774)
> at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Surface.java:473)
> at android.view.SurfaceView$1.unlockCanvasAndPost(SurfaceView.java:1629)
> at com.example.lab10.TaskSix$OvalsView.surfaceCreated$lambda$0(TaskSix.kt:136)
> at com.example.lab10.TaskSix$OvalsView.$r8$lambda$fxYnyciEdLkjDqbt7r8jlbaJ-60(Unknown Source:0)
> at com.example.lab10.TaskSix$OvalsView$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

```
package com.example.lab10
    
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    
    
    import android.content.Context
    import android.graphics.Canvas
    import android.graphics.Color
    import android.graphics.Paint
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.MotionEvent
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder
    import android.view.SurfaceView
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.WindowManager
    import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    
    class TaskSix : AppCompatActivity() {
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_six)
    
            title = "Task#6"
    
            val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout)
            val ovalsView =  OvalsView(this)
    
            layout.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
                when (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN -> {
                        Log.d("qqq", "down")
                        val ID: Int = motionEvent.getPointerId(motionEvent.getActionIndex())
                        Log.d("qqq", "element with id: $ID")
    
    
                        layout.addView(ovalsView)
    
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                        Log.d("qqq", "move")
                        var idx = 0
                        while (idx < motionEvent.pointerCount) {
                            val ID: Int = motionEvent.getPointerId(idx) // pobranie unikalnego id dla każdego dotyku
                            idx++
    
                            ovalsView._top = motionEvent.y
                            ovalsView._left = motionEvent.x
                        }
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> {
                        Log.d("qqq", "up")
    
                        layout.removeView(ovalsView)
    
                    }
                    else -> Log.d("qqq", "unhandled")
                }
                return@OnTouchListener true
            })
    
        }
    
        private class OvalsView(context: Context) : SurfaceView(context), SurfaceHolder.Callback {
            private val mSurfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder
            private val mPainter = Paint()
            private var mDrawingThread: Thread? = null
            private val mDisplay = DisplayMetrics()
            private var mDisplayWidth: Int
            private var mDisplayHeight: Int
            private var mRotation = 0f
    
            var _top: Float = 0f
            var _left: Float = 0f
    
            init {
                val wm = context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
                wm.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(mDisplay)
                mDisplayWidth = mDisplay.widthPixels
                mDisplayHeight = mDisplay.heightPixels
                mPainter.isAntiAlias = true
                mPainter.color = Color.RED
                mSurfaceHolder = holder
                mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this)
            }
    
            private fun animateOvals(): Boolean {
                mRotation += 1
                return true
            }
            private fun drawWheel(canvas: Canvas) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
    //            canvas.rotate(mRotation, mDisplayWidth / 2f, mDisplayHeight / 2f)
    
                //drawOval(float left, float top, float right, float bottom, @NonNull Paint paint)
    
    //            canvas.drawOval(mDisplayWidth/2f - 100f/2f - 100f, mDisplayHeight/2 + 100f/2f,
    //                mDisplayWidth/2f + 100f/2f + 100f, mDisplayHeight/2f - 100/2f, mPainter)
    
                if (_top > 0f && _left > 0f)
                    canvas.drawOval(_left, _top, _left + 200f, _top + 350f, mPainter)
            }
    
            override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
                mDisplayWidth = w
                mDisplayHeight = h
                super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
            }
    
            override fun surfaceChanged(holder: SurfaceHolder, format: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {
            }
    
            override fun surfaceDestroyed(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
                if (mDrawingThread != null) {
                    mDrawingThread!!.interrupt()
                }
    
            }
    
            override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder) {
    
                mDrawingThread = Thread(Runnable {
                    var MAX_FRAME_TIME = 1000/60
    
                    var frameStartTime = System.nanoTime();
                    var frameTime: Long = 0
                    var canvas: Canvas? = null
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted && animateOvals()) {
    
                        canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()
                        if (canvas != null) {
                            drawWheel(canvas)
                            mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas)
                        }
    
    
                        frameTime = (System.nanoTime() - frameStartTime) / 1000000
                        if (frameTime < MAX_FRAME_TIME) // faster than the max fps - limit the FPS
                        {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(MAX_FRAME_TIME - frameTime)
                            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                                // ignore
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                mDrawingThread!!.start()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to dig into the Android source and find out exactly what's happening, but your crash is being generated by that `Runnable` interacting with the `Surface`'s `Canvas` (creating the *"Surface has been released"* exception).

When you lift your finger, you do this:

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP -> {
    layout.removeView(ovalsView)
}
```

And in [the docs for `removeView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup#removeView(android.view.View)):

> **Note**: do not invoke this method from `View.draw(android.graphics.Canvas)`, `View.onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)`, `dispatchDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)` **or any related method**.

Which implies to me that calling `removeView` will cause things to happen to the `View` which mean they can no longer be drawn to, which is why you can't do it from inside one of the `draw` calls where you're actively drawing to their `Canvas`.

---

Since your drawing thread is constantly drawing to the `Surface` on a tick, you have a potential race condition where the `Surface` is *released* before the thread is interrupted. And you call `interrupt()` in `surfaceDestroyed` - but *releasing* happens before the `Surface` is actually *destroyed*, [it just releases a reference and makes the Surface *invalid*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface#release()).

So your drawing loop is probably still attempting to draw to that released, invalid `Surface` - there are lots of ways to get around this, but you might want to look at [`Surface#isValid`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Surface#isValid()) (you can access a `SurfaceView`'s underlying surface with [`getHolder()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView#getHolder())). And since you have multiple threads here, you might want to implement some kind of concurrent locking to avoid the UI thread invalidating the `Surface` with `removeView` while the drawing thread is running the `Canvas`-touching code, which could cause rare crashes

Comment: I did something like this but it still doesn't work: ```... if (mSurfaceHolder.surface.isValid) { canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(); if (canvas != null) { drawWheel(canvas); mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); } } ...```

Comment: @np. you might want to set a flag in your `OvalsView` then that makes the drawing active or not, and set that true after adding your view to the layout (might have to be after the first layout pass), false when you remove it. Then have the drawing loop check it before attempting to do anything. You'll have to make it `@Volatile` or something since you're using separate threads. I can't give you any specific advice because I haven't added and removed surfaces like this so I'm not sure what lifecycle stuff you need to worry about. A basic custom view might be easier if you're not tied to this